# Using random variables in mocked apollo react testing generates "Error: No more mocked responses for the query" error

Tags: unit-testing, apollo, react-testing-library

In a React and GraphQL project, I have a mutation which looks like this:

```
const variables: {
    id: faker.random.uuid(),
    //other info
}

client.mutate({
  mutation: CREATE_PERSON,
  variables,
  update: updateFct
}).then(result => {
    // do something with the result
})
}).catch(error => {
    //do something with error
});
```

and I'm testing it using [@apollo/react-testing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@apollo/react-testing) as described in [the official documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/testing/#testing-mutations).

The mock I used looks like this:

```
const mocks = [
    {
        request: {
            query: CREATE_PERSON,
            variables: {
                id: 'd6d98b88-c866-4496-9bd4-de7ba48d0f52'
                // other info
            }
        },
        result: {
            data: {
                createPerson {
                    id: 'd6d98b88-c866-4496-9bd4-de7ba48d0f52',
                    // other info
                }
            }
        }
    }
];
```

I know the source of the problem: the fact that in the production code I'm using a random UUID, when I launch my test I got the famous error:

> Error: No more mocked responses for the query...

I'm familiar with solving this error (like taking care of *__typename* ...etc.) but in this case I know that my problem is related to the use of a random UUID in my variables and I can confirm that by replacing the line

```
const variables: {
    id: faker.random.uuid(),
    //other info
}
```

with

```
const variables: {
    id: 'd6d98b88-c866-4496-9bd4-de7ba48d0f52',
    //other info
}
```

and my test pass (but of course it's not the goal, I need to use a random variable value).

Any feedback or past experience with a such use case?

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem is the `faker.random.uuid` returning a random id, you can mock that module out to return a set value.

In jest, you can do it by setting up a [mocked module](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks). For example, if using an npm `faker` package:

```
// __mocks__/faker.js
module.exports = {
    random: {
        uuid: () => 'some-random-uuid',
    }
}
```

Now when your tests are running, the function the calls `faker.random.uuid()` and gets `'some-random-uuid'`. In your test, you can call that module and also receive the mocked value:

```
import faker from 'faker'

const variables: {
    id: faker.random.uuid(), // returns 'some-random-uuid'
    //other info
}
```